# Fluid Dynamics Buoynacy Question

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

I am actually studying maths but have to do a fluid dynamics module. I'm revising for my exams but can't get my head around this question even though I know it should be straight forward.

The densities of wood, copper and water are:

$\rho_{\text{wood}} = 600 \ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$

$\rho_{\text{copper}} = 8900\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$

$\rho_{\text{water}} = 1000 \ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$

what mass of copper in kg must be attached to a piece of wood of mass $0.5$ kg so that the copper and wood, together, will just submerge under water?

I have the solution which is apparently $0.375$ kg. But I have no idea how we get to this.

Answer (score 0):

Total mass
$$m_t = m_1+ m_2 = 0.5 \text{kg} + m_2$$

Total volume
$$v_t = v_1 + v_2 = 0.5 \text{kg}/ 600 \text {kg}/\text{m}^3 + m_2 / 8900 \text{kg}/\text{m}^3$$

Now, what's the expression for total density, and what does it need to equal?

Comment: So, total density is rho_t = rho_1 + rho_2 = 0.5kg/v_1 + m_2/8900kg/m^3. Is it that this total density is equal to rho_water*v_t

Comment: Hmm, no. Density is mass/volume so in this problem the total desired density of the combined items is $d_t = m_t/v_t $. For the combined items to just submerge, that density must be the same as the density of water.

Comment: Not trying to confuse things by using $d $ instead of $\rho $ for density.  It's what I typed at the time and I can't edit the comment now.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve $1000 = m_{t}/v_{t}=\rho_{t}$ and find $m_{2}$. This is saying total density of copper and wood must be equal to total density of water.